# Showing Mic and Send button together on Botframework WebChat

Tags: javascript, reactjs, botframework, chatbot, web-chat

I am working on a Botframework V4.6 using the VA Template. For communication with the Bot I am using the React Web Chat.

When enabling the Speech to Text service on the React application, Mic button shows up

[image: Microphone]

but the Mic button hides the send button, for UX on mobile i need the two buttons to exist, how should i show the Mic button and the Send button together?

is it a supported feature or should i workaround it?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Web Chat does not support utilizing both the microphone and the send button at the same time. While it is technically possible to get both to display, when the microphone is enabled it overwrites certain classes that the send button relies on. So, while both buttons will display, the send button will never be functional.

If you feel this would be a good feature for Web Chat to include, I would suggest you present it as a feature request [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/new?assignees=&labels=Enhancement%2C+Pending%2C+customer-reported%2C+Bot+Services&template=feature_request.md&title=).

Hope of help!

Comment: Do you have any resource to explain why this is not supported? because it seems like this is intended to be like this. 
I would like to check why they are forcing these features,

Comment: No, there is no resource but I’ll speak with the principal dev and see if there was a reason. If you consider other services, it really just comes down to what they decided to implement. WhatsApp, for instance, has no send button, only a record button. And the record button doesn’t dictate your message as STT. It records your message as a file to be played, aka a voice note. Put simply, that is the design choice they made. It may be configurable, I don’t know as I haven’t looked into it. But, at face value, that is what you get. The same could be said for Web Chat.